# Stretching of geometry when rasterizing vector data on Google Maps

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, rasterization

I'll start with a quick backstory on what I am trying to achieve.  I'm working on an offline Android GIS tool and people are throwing giant datasets at it.  It converts these into Google features (V2) and in the case of shapefiles or KML's with tens of thousands of features it overloads the rendering capacity and memory, making the map choppy.

I had the idea of rasterizing these datasets on the fly.  My approach is a little naive in that I am simply converting the Lat/Longs to image space, drawing the features on a canvas and then throwing the Bitmap on the map as a GroundOverlay.  Over small areas it is pixel perfect:

[image] 
[image]

However over a much larger geographical area there is a pronounced vertical warping of the geometry:

[image]
[image]

The boundaries of the rasterized image line up perfectly with the datasets but the internal features warp vertically away from the equator.  I'm guessing there is some sort of projection issue at play but I am lost.

Could someone explain what I am seeing and how to correct the alignment?

Comment: you need to tile your raster like google maps tiles see http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ slice your large image up into smaller tiles will work

Comment: @mapperz - Turning it into a tile provider was going to be my next step but wouldn't I end up with the same vertical warping just in a patchwork.  At Zoom 2 for example wouldn't this be exactly the same result.  Or is there something different about how tiles are rendered compared to an overlay?